# Autolayout Height >= 0 Frame in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, autolayout, interface-builder

I'm using interface builder to set up a table view cell with two labels. One of them should have dynamic height, depending on how much text it holds. (The cell is also of dynamic height based on the height of that label.) I have the constraints working properly – both the label and the cell resize correctly based on input text. My problem is that to make it work I had to set a constraint on the resizing label of height >= 0. For some reason, IB forces me to make the on-screen height of the label 0, which makes it hard to see/work with. The little dots below "Label" is the 0-height label:

[image]

If I set it at a height greater than 0 (which should be allowed by the constraint) the constraint turns red in error:

[image]

I'm curious why IB won't let me set something with a >= constraint on its height at a height greater than the minimum value. Is there a way I can get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0):

While working with label text you don't require to give the height to `UILabel`. As it will automatically take the height based on font size. All you need to do is give vertical,top and bottom constraint to both the labels and remove the default text from attributes inspector. Now you can create table cell with dynamic height.

**Top Label constraints:**
leading,Trailing,Top

**Bottom Label constraints:**
leading,Trailing,Bottom
and also give vertical spacing between top and bottom label.

And with the self sizing cell height you can get you desired result.

ref url:  [self-sizing-cells](http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/).

Here is the image of constraints which i've set:
[image]

Here is the image of constraints for both the label.
[image]
[image: Label1 with text]
[image]
[image: Label2 without text]

And the sample code which i've added to display data with result.
[image]

Hope it helps in solving your problem.

Comment: It seems like you are having the issue I am trying to avoid though (your second label appears to be 0 height in IB

Comment: @MattCooper My second label is of 0 height because there is no content to second label so it's height will automatically becomes 0. When working with label you don't require height constraint. As height of label will automatically increase or decrease based on the string you pass in it. So what I'm saying is that the height constraint which you have given to label is not required.

Comment: When I don't give my labels height constraints, I get "Height is ambiguous for Label" (the top label) and "Height and vertical position are ambiguous for Label2" (the lower label). How are you avoiding these errors?

Comment: @MattCooper If you are getting this It means that now you have removed the label text and it's height has changed to 0px. So now the issue would be of vertical spacing. What you must do is change the height of you cell which should be summation of vertical constraint. Ex: TopLabel = 10, VerticalSpace = 10, BottomLabel = 10, TopLabelHeight = 10 or 0, BottomLabelHeight = 10 or 0. So the height of cell in your storyboard should be (TopLabel +TopLabelHeight +VerticalSpace +BottomLabelHeight + BottomLabel).

Comment: In first case both label height is 10 so height of cell would be 50 which would not work in ur case currently.  In second case both label height is 0 so height of cell would be 30 which would not work in ur case currently. Pl. check in the last image what I've done so that height of cell will get changed automatically at runtime based on label text. If still you face problem do let me know.